# Maintain keyframes when transcoding and removing b-frames

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, keyframe, h.265, transcode

I need to transcode a video from H.265 in a `.mov` container to H.264 in a `.mkv` container and would like to remove b-frames. The command to do that with `ffmpeg` is relatively straightforward [0], but it appears to be removing keyframes and using scene detection for when to use them.

Is there a way to have it maintain the keyframes in the output?

0: `ffmpeg -i <input.mov> -vcodec libx264 -bf 0 -acodec copy <output.mkv>`

Comment: Does `-discard nokey` input option work for you?

Comment: I tried that and it only transcoded the first few seconds of the video and the output file only plays the audio in VLC (i.e. the video doesn't show up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i <input.mov> -force_key_frames source -vcodec libx264 -bf 0 -acodec copy <output.mkv>`

This will place KFs at same timestamps* as in the source.

*note that bacause of timestamp rounding due to a likely change of track timebase, the timestamps may not be identical.

Comment: Could we use `-enc_time_base -1` to fix the keep the same timebase?

Comment: That's the encoder time base. MKV has a fixed TB of 1/1000, so no.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.